Is this an invitation to submit or a polite rejection?
I have sent an email to an editor of a highly competitive math journal, asking if they think I should submit my paper there or not. The editor is an expert in the field of the paper, so my email was not just a cold call. This is the response I received:

I had a quick look at the paper. At the moment we have a large number
of submissions and we have to be very selective. However, the first
scan is typically very quick and it seems to me your paper deserves to
be considered at least for quick opinions by [name of the journal].

Should I submit or is this a nice way to suggest not to submit?
Update: That paper passed the quick opinion and it's under review, so I assume the message was indeed encouraging me to submit.

In my experience, this would indicate that your submission does meet a certain minimal standard... so it is not getting a "desk rejection". Getting "quick opinions" is meant to be a non-trivial filter, so it seems that the editor is at least taking your paper seriously.
A virtue of "quick opinions" is that, if the conclusion is rejection, it won't take a year!

Thank you for your response. I submitted the paper a little less than four weeks ago, and it’s still in the "editor assigned" status. Based on your experience, how long do these quick opinions typically take?

Perhaps a month or two, ideally.

Here is my interpretation of what the email is saying:

I had a quick look at the paper.

The editor looked at your paper, probably for about 5-10 minutes, reading the abstract and parts of your introduction, description of your main result etc. That's really good - probably the best you can hope for from an email to someone like that. If they thought your paper was junk they wouldn't spend more than two minutes on it, and wouldn't describe themselves as having "had a quick look at the paper".

At the moment we have a large number of submissions and we have to be very selective.

They want you to know that your expectations should be low. The probability of rejection if you submit your paper is quite high; not necessarily because your paper isn't good, but mostly because the journal receives a lot of high quality submissions and can only accept a relatively small fraction of them.

However, the first scan is typically very quick and it seems to me your paper deserves to be considered at least for quick opinions by [name of the journal].

The editor looked at the paper just long enough to form the opinion that it's good enough to not be outright rejected. Again, I think that's a very positive statement and probably the most you can hope for from sending this sort of pre-submission query email. What it means is that if you submit the paper and whoever is assigned to handle it shares this editor's opinion, it will be sent for a quick opinion by an expert in the field (which is standard procedure these days in top math journals).
After that, no one can say what will happen. It could get rejected after the quick opinion comes back (which will happen very quickly, usually in about 1-2 weeks); or it could pass the quick opinion filter and then get sent out for a full review, which could typically take 3-12 months, following which, it will either be accepted (with no or minor revisions), rejected, or there will be recommendations for a major revision with another round of review after that.
To summarize, this email seems to me as encouraging as it gets with top journals. The only reason for the tentative/hesitant language is that the editor believes (probably based on past experience) that using stronger/more positive language might mislead an inexperienced author into thinking that their chances are higher than they are.

Should I submit or is this a nice way to suggest not to submit?

Your chances of the paper getting rejected are still high as I said, but the email suggests that they are no higher than they were a priori before you sent the query email; in fact, they are probably lower than the a priori estimate. Based on the email, I would say that submitting the paper would be tantamount to playing a game with a risk/reward profile that looks something like this:

50% chance of a quick rejection after 1-2 weeks
35% chance of a rejection after 3-12 months
15% chance of acceptance after 3-12 months

(These numbers are for illustration only, obviously I know nothing about your paper so I'm just making up rough numbers for a generic example paper that loosely fits your description. You can tweak them based on your own idea of how good your paper is.)
You should submit if this kind of gamble makes sense for your career goals and situation. Good luck!

+1 The emphasis on the quickness of the initial phase also could indicate "Don't worry about wasting experts' time by submitting this paper, it's worth looking into."

To me that sounds like they welcome you to submit it and at the least you might get a quick feedback on your paper.

"Quick opinions" don't typically provide any meaningful feedback to the author - the purpose is to quickly determine if the paper should actually go out for serious peer review (which could take a year or more).  One might think of it as a way for the editor to get an informed opinion on whether or not to make a desk rejection rather than as actual peer review.
